# notepad++ how to use regex to find lines that have two capital letters in a row?

Tags: notepad

how to use regular expression to find strings containing two capital letters in a row?

```
   ^([A-Z\s]+)$
```

Comment: do those letters need to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes, they must be consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^.*[A-Z]{2}.*$` matches as follows

```
^        Beginning of the line
.*       Any char for any number of times
[A-Z]{2} Two consecutive capital letters 
.*       Any char for any number of times
$        End of line
```

Find a live example here:
https://regex101.com/r/m2hPbh/1

Answer (score 1):

`([A-Z][A-Z][a-z0-9]*)` would find every word that contains 2 capital letters in a row